# css box alignment issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, alignment

I can't seem to figure out how to align the top of img and copy elements in the promo div. Any thoughts? This doesn't lign up correctly in chrome.

I have looked through a lot of the other questions and cannot seem to figure it out.

At the end of the day i want to be able to have a punch out box at the top left of the div, but I want to make sure that the text overflow does not wrap around the image.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
.promo {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: pink;
}
.promo img {
float: left;
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
background-color: orange;
}
.copy {
    float: left;
    width: 152px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="promo"> <img src="" alt="" />
  <p class="copy">This is the content. I have a lot of contentfff this it s a fodis sod sod sfns s ndosn</p>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div class="promo"> <img src="" alt=""/>
  <p class="copy">This is the content. I have a lot of contentfff this it s a fodis sod sod sfns s ndosn</p>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div class="promo"> <img src="" alt=""/>
  <p class="copy">This is the content. I have a lot of contentfff this it s a fodis sod sod sfns s ndosn</p>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I plugged your code into [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gRFBP/) and it's giving me a happy face when I view it in chrome. Is this still not doing what you want?

Comment: For some reason this seems to work in jsfiddle, but if you take the code and put it into a html file and then open it in chrome the text seems to come up half way up the image.

Comment: That extra space is there because you need to reset the default styling of `p` tags by applying `margin:0;` on them. If you turn off Normalized.css in jsFiddle, you can observe this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/NuVww/21/ ?

Comment: Sadly, this is not what I am looking for, I want the text and the image to line up along the top.